# Is it possible to capture and store the source database ID in the destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm doing a research these days on SSIS and I have a question that I was unable to find a correct answer to.

1. Is it possible for SSIS to extract a source database identifier and to store in the destination so that when we look at each data row, it says from which system it came from when you have multiple source systems for SSIS to extract data from?

Comment: You could use the [database identification number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186274.aspx) for this.  Use the function `DB_ID()` to return.  Alternatively you could capture the [server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx) and [db name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189753.aspx), in separate columns - `SELECT @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be straightforward. I would use a SQL Task to get your identifier from the source database and save it into a variable. Inside your data flow from the source database, add a derived column component that adds the variable in as a new column - this can then be inserted into a column in the destination table.

Obviously this will depend of where your source database identifier comes from, I'm assuming that it can be queried, if this is not the case, you can adjust my method appropriately.